# Trying to store API data fetched with Retrofit2 in a mutableList, returns an empty list

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit2, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to add sports API data to a list of categories to be synchronized with a scrollable tabrow, but the list is always empty and just shows the titles and icons, not the API data. The application is working perfect with a dummy list, and this is not the case when adding from an API.

I attached some code samples to make it obvious.
I hope I make a clear explanation, and someone may give an answer.

ListViewModel

```
class ListViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val tournamentItemList: MutableList<Category>
        get() = items

    private val items = mutableStateListOf<Category>()

    fun addTournamentItem(item: Category){
        items.add(item)
    }
}
```

GetData

```
@Composable
fun GetData(
    team: TeamStatsResponse, rankList: List<StandingsItemItem?>
) {
    val data: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList(3)
    val viewModel: TournamentStateViewModel = viewModel()
    viewModel.addTournamentItem(
        Category(
            "Standings",
            Icons.Default.TableRows,
            onClick = {},
            data.forEach {
                TopTeamsPoints(
                    rankList[it]!!.rank!!,
                    rankList[it]!!.team!!.logo!!,
                    rankList[it]!!.team!!.name!!,
                    rankList[it]!!.all!!.played!!,
                    rankList[it]!!.all!!.win!!,
                    rankList[it]!!.all!!.draw!!,
                    rankList[it]!!.all!!.lose!!,
                    rankList[it]!!.points!!
                )
            }
        )
    )
    viewModel.addTournamentItem(
        Category(
            "Clean Sheets",
            Icons.Default.CleaningServices,
            onClick = {},
            data.forEach {
                TopTeamsClean(
                    1, team.team!!.logo!!,
                    team.team.name!!, team.fixtures!!.played!!.total!!,
                    team.cleanSheet!!.total!!
                )
            }
        )
    )
    etc...
}
```

FetchData

```
fun FetchData(
    mainViewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    when(
        val stateA = mainViewModel.pLStandings.collectAsState().value
    ) {
        is PLStandingsState.Empty -> {
            Text(text = "No data available")
        }
        is PLStandingsState.Loading -> {
            Text(text = "Loading...")
        }
        is PLStandingsState.Error -> {
            Text(text = stateA.message)
        }
        is PLStandingsState.Success -> {
            when(val stateB = mainViewModel.leagueStatsState.collectAsState().value) {
                is LeagueStatsState.Empty -> {
                    Text(text = "No data available")
                }
                is LeagueStatsState.Loading -> {
                    Text(text = "Loading...")
                }
                is LeagueStatsState.Error -> {
                    Text(text = stateB.message)
                }
                is LeagueStatsState.Success -> {
                    GetData(team = stateB.teamData, rankList = stateA.data)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun TabSyncCompose() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val viewModel: TournamentStateViewModel = viewModel()
    val list = viewModel.tournamentItemList
    if (list.isNotEmpty()) {
        TabSyncComposeScreen(list)
    } else {
        //This toast always appears
        Toast.makeText(context, "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: So, where exactly is the problem? Does the HTTP request work? Is it the transformation of the data to your model that's not working? Does displaying the model in the UI work? Please edit your question to only contain the relevant code that fails and describe what you would expect from that piece of code.

Comment: @Leviathan
The same data above is working fine and is successfully fetched from the API, and it's successfully appears when adding the same data to a LazyColumn (For example).
So, the problem here, I think with the MutableList or the way of storing data in that list.

Comment: @Leviathan
I will attach the code with the same data in the details Standing activity, and it's working without problems.

Comment: And please remove all code that is not pertitent to the current problem. It distracts from what is important. Please follow the [guideline to produce a minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Although you still do not tell us specifically I assume the list in question is `tournamentItemList`. Now, what exactly is your problem? Does that list not contain the expected data? Or is the list properly populated but it isn't displayed correctly? Please be explicit about this in your question and remove the irrelevant code parts.

Comment: @Leviathan
Simply, the problem is that the else block is executed and the "Empty" Toast appeared.
So, the list is empty, and this is the problem. Why the list is empty?

Comment: When your problem is that the list is empty, then certainly it is irrelevant how that (empty) list is displayed in your UI. So why does your question still contain UI code?

Comment: `GetData` seems to properly populate your list. That also doesn't seem to be your problem. I reiterate my inital request that you provide us with a minimal reproducible example. Your code is neither minimal nor reproducible. The question will be closed if you fail to produce an MRE. Please carefully re-read the link I provided and make sure your question fully conforms to the guideline layed out therein.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm confused. The titles and icons inside the list added are displayed in the UI, but with no API data. On the other hand, Toast appears every time the app is created.

Comment: @Leviathan
I'm really trying to add the most relevant code, and I'm trying to make it minimized.
I'm trying to implement the library with the API data.

https://github.com/Ahmad-Hamwi/TabSync/tree/master/compose-app/src/main/java/com/ahmadhamwi/tabsync_compose_example

Answer (score 0):

OK, In the attached code samples above, without any edits, the data was successfully fetched from the API and added successfully to the list. The real problem is with the 'data' array list of 3 integers. While the wanted items from the API are only 3, then the loop is not required. For me, everything is now working perfectly after removing 'add' and 'foreach{}' blocks.

```
viewModel.addTournamentItem(
        Category(
            "Standings",
            Icons.Default.TableRows,
            onClick = {},
            TopTeamsPoints(
                rankList[0]!!.rank!!,
                rankList[0]!!.team!!.logo!!,
                rankList[0]!!.team!!.name!!,
                rankList[0]!!.all!!.played!!,
                rankList[0]!!.all!!.win!!,
                rankList[0]!!.all!!.draw!!,
                rankList[0]!!.all!!.lose!!,
                rankList[0]!!.points!!
            )
            etc...
        )
    )
```